# Startactivity for result with causes crash

Tags: android, pointers, nullpointerexception, null, startactivityforresult

I am trying to learn Android Studio and my first app is a blood alcohol calculator. The user starts that app and then a new activity is started so that they can enter their weight and press ok, this returns them back to the main activity and fills in the weight text.

I use `startActivityForResult` and then `putExtra` in the second activity. The first activity crashes if I use the `getExtra` method, if I delete the 2 receiving lines of code then there is no crash. When I use the debugger it says `NullPointerException` just before it says App has stopped working

Main activity code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      static int displayunit = 0;
      static double percentage = 5.0;
      static int change = 1;
      static double bah;
      static double vol = 25;
      static double timestamp = 0;
      static double w = 0;
      static String we = "a";
      final int rcode = 3;
      final String[] units = {"Small Shot(25ml)", "Large Shot(35ml)", "Small 
    Port/Sherry(50ml)", "Large Port/Sherry(70ml)", "Small Wine(125ml)", 
    "Large 
    Wine(175ml)", "Small Beer Bottle(284ml)", "Half Pint(236.6ml)", "Medium 
    Beer Bottle(330ml)", "Can of beer(440ml)", "Large Bottle(500ml)", 
    "Pint(568.26ml)", "Massive Beer Bottle(660ml)"};
    final int[] unitsum = {25, 35, 50, 70, 125, 175, 284, 237, 330, 440, 500, 
    569, 660};

      @Override

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();





 intent.setClassName("com.example.alccalc","com.example.alccalc.enterweight");
            if(w ==0){
             startActivityForResult(intent, rcode);
            }

      }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult ( int requstCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent intent){
                if (requstCode == rcode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    we = getIntent().getStringExtra("weighttext");
                    w = Double.parseDouble(we);
                }
                TextView kg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kg);
                kg.setText(we)

Second Activity

    public class enterweight extends Activity {

    EditText entweight;
    TextView tester;
    String weightstring;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle State) {
    super.onCreate(State);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enterweight);

    entweight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entweight);
    tester = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tester);


    Button okweight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okweight);
    okweight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            weightstring = entweight.getText().toString();
            //tester.setText(weightstring);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra
                        ("weighttext", weightstring);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                if (intent.hasExtra("weighttext")) {
                    finish();
                }


        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question and include the stack trace.

Comment: You are on the right track by trying to use a debugger.  Can you tell us on exactly which line the activity is crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here `getIntent();`

Since you are using the `onActivityResult ( int requstCode, int resultCode, 
Intent intent)` method, you can find your extras in the variable `intent`.  The method `getIntent()` returns the intent that is used to start the activity. In your case it is `null`.

Use:

```
we = intent.getStringExtra("weighttext");
```

instead of

```
we = getIntent().getStringExtra("weighttext");
```

Better:

```
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
           String result = extras.getString("weighttext");
           .....
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I tried it and it worked.  Amazing to see it actually work and not crash after weeks of crashing.

Comment: Hi @percy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your receiving code

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
Bundle b =  intent.getExtras();
if(b != null)
we = b.getString("weighttext");
```

Comment: It is wrong. getIntent() in this case is null. He has to use the variable intent in the onActivityResult method.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getIntent()` to get the result data. `getIntent()` is an activity method that returns an intent that is used to start the activity. You should use the `intent` variable that is passed on `onActivityResult` method.

`if (requstCode == rcode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    we = intent.getStringExtra("weighttext");
    w = Double.parseDouble(we);
}`